# NUnit exe file cannot found in the system

Tags: windows-8.1

I've just started with NUnit and downloaded `NUnit 2.6.4` from [here](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=download).

I want to run my test case with NUnit GUI. So, I've installed it on my system *(windows 8.1)*, but the .exe file is not found any where!

When I install the .msi file, it's just installed successfully each time but doesn't display on *apps/startmenu*.

So, I've looked in program file as well, but in the folder of NUnit there is no application file.

Am i missing something?

Comment: Did you supply a path for the installer? Did you check that directory?

Comment: @Seth: Actually no, I've not supplied any path. There is no such option provided!

Comment: Default would be `%programfiles(x86)%\NUnit 2.6.4` so e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.6.4`.

Comment: @Seth: Yeah, there is a folder `NUnit 2.6.4` in my program files, but there is just icon file and dlls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default installation path seems to be `%programfiles(x86)%\NUnit 2.6.4` as you said there just a bunch of DLLs available you probably grabbed the wrong package.

By following the link you gave you'd end up on the [github page](https://github.com/nunit/nunitv2/releases/tag/2.6.4) for the release. Which has a whole bunch of downloads available. If you really only have the DLLs in that directory check which MSI you downloaded. There is a `NUnit-2.6.4-net-1.1.msi` and a `NUnit-2.6.4.msi` while the first is less than 1 MB the second is around 3 MB. The latter does seem to contain all the files.

If you did download the second file there is probably a different problem.